# Yii: Reference to an other object

Tags: php, yii

How can I change the `view.php` code (as autogenerated by Gii of Yii framework) to show a link to another object (with a title and link), instead of a simple numeric id?

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('employee')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->employee); ?>
<br />
```

I can do it with `findByPk` and `CHtml::link`, but maybe there is a shorter way? Please give me the shortest code to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the route to view an employee is `employee/view` and his name is stored in `name` and his id in `id`, the shortest way to code it would be:

```
CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->employee->name), array('employee/view', 'id' => $data->employee->id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use createUrl:

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->employee), 
    Yii::app()->createUrl('/model/view', array(
       'id' => $data->employee->id
));
 ?>
```

Don't forget to:

- replace `model` with the name of your model,
- modify your view action in your controller